# Find out which raw material made a manufactured product

Tags: sql, oracle

I've being trying to solve this for two days now. I work with manufacturing control. A client has asked me to calculate the raw material consumption for their products. The data is stored in two table, *item* and *material*,
in the former table is stored the begin and end time for manufacturing the item, in the latter table is stored when the raw material was put in the machine and 
which lot was used.

The manufacturing process is like this: the operator adds the 
raw materials to the machine, input the time at a terminal. Some time later he starts the machine, and it fuses kilometers of plastic films, each item is a roll of that film that usually weight hundreds of kilos. The machine automatically insert the begin and end time of each roll in the *item* table.

When the raw material is about to be expended, the operator stops the machine and insert more raw materials from a different lot, and then starts the machine again.

Depending on the size of the lot, it can last several rolls, or a single roll can be made from different lots of materials,

*Item table*

```
| begin_time  | end_time  | item |
|-------------|-----------|------|
|   8:49      | 9:29      |   1  |
|   9:29      | 10:04     |   2  |
|  10:04      | 10:42     |   3  |
```

*Material Table*

```
| begin_time | material |
|------------|----------|
| 7:21       | A1       |
| 7:21       | A2       |
| 9:39       | B1       |
| 9:39       | B2       |
| 9:50       | C1       |
| 9:51       | C2       |
|10:14       | D1       |   
|10:14       | D2       |
```

As it can be see the first item was done with material A1 and A2, but the second item started with A1,A2 then changed to B1,B2 and finished
with C1 and C2
I'm having problems trying to relate which raw material lot was used in which item.

I have tried several variation on queries like this

```
select p.item,i.material
from product p
join (
      select distinct a.begin_time as dt1, b.begin_time  as dt2
      from material a 
      join material b on a.begin_time < b.begin_time
) i on i.dt1 > p.begin_time and i.dt2 <= p.end_time
where p.item = 2
```

The result for that query would be something like that

```
|  item  |  material |
|--------|-----------|
|    1   |    A1     |
|    1   |    A2     |
|    2   |    A1     |
|    2   |    A2     |
|    2   |    B1     |
|    2   |    B2     |
|    2   |    C1     |
|    2   |    C2     |
|    3   |    C1     |
|    3   |    C2     |
|    3   |    D1     |
|    3   |    D2     |
```

Comment: How do you get A1/A2 for the second item?

Comment: Each item in `Material` table has only `begin_time`. I guess that there is also `end_time` bound to this item, but not stored in this table, Am I right ? If yes, then please explain how do you determine this `end time` for a given item for example for items: `B1` and `B2` .

Comment: @GordonLinoff By time , A1/A2 were already in the machine when the second item started being made, just after some minutes B1/B2 were added

Comment: @kordirko Yes, you are right. There is only begin_time for raw materials, it's the moment the material were added in the machine to manufacture the item. The begin and end time for the item is added automatically into the table by the machine, I have to then look which raw material were used.

Comment: @mmaximo . . . I read the materials table and come to the conclusion that nanoparticles of  A1 were inserted in the machine at 7:21.  These lasted for seconds and were replaced by A2 less than a minute later.  A2 survived until a similar process repeated with B1/B2 at 9:39.  In other words, there seems to be domain knowledge present neither in the data nor the question.

Comment: If there is ony `begin_time` for raw material stored in the table, then how do you determine a moment when the machine consume all of this material ? Without knowing that it is impossible to determine which materials were used to produce given items. The material was added to the machine at X o'clock .... and all items produced after this time can use this material, because we don't know the time when the machine exhausts that material.

Comment: @GordonLinoff No, both A1 and A2 were inserted at the same time and continuously until they were expended and replaced by B1/B2. I will modify my question to include a explanation about the manufactoring process.

Comment: @kordirko the end time for one material is the begin_time for the next, this machine cannot run without raw material.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the explanation. One more question - C1 was placed at 9:50 and C2 was placed at 9:51 into the machine. Which time is the "end-time" of B1 and B2, is it 9:50, 9:51 ? I guess that there are two "slots" in the machine, and two materials can be put into the machine at once, but not more than 2.

Comment: @kordirko yes, you are right there are two independent slots in the machine,  but usually they are replace at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know there are two slots, then the logic is:  For each item in the item table, get the materials that are in the table in the specified time *plus* the two materials just before the time.  In Oracle, you can do this using a `union all` query:

```
select i.item, m.material, m.begin_time
from items i join
     materials m
     on m.begin_time  between i.begin_time and i.end_time
union all
select item, material, begin_time
from (select i.item, m.material, m.begin_time,
             row_number() over (partition by i.item order by m.begin_time desc) as seqnum
      from items i join
           materials m
           on m.begin_time < i.begin_time 
     ) im
where seqnum <= 2;
```